# Android App - Denied Amazon App Market Slider Interruption

Tags: android, slider, publish, amazon-appstore

Hi just tried uploading an app to the amazon market, it was revoked with this message:

> *OS Version: [2.2] Device/Form Factor:*
>
> *[Motorola Droid 2]*
>
> *Bug Description: Slider Interruption issue*

So this says:

Android 2.2 on a Motorola Droid 2

But question is, does anyone have official wording on '**Slider Interruption**', does this mean when the screen is moved up to show the keyboard?

I though if I set android:orientation="portrait" the app would ignore the slide. Is it different on the Droid 2?

Comment: If the orientation is set in the manifest file with orientation:portrait under the activity and onConfigChanges is not set in the manifest file then it is not an orientation, keyboard slide.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What do you mean by "it is not an orientation, keyboard slide" What does that infer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Slider Interruption' - **does** mean when the screen is moved up to show the keyboard

> this will cause the activity to go into onPause onStop and on somephones even onDestroy then onCreate / onStart onResume

Answer (score 1):

Ask Amazon for clarification. My experience with them has been horrible. My app was denied, with the following message.

> The application crashes upon launch with the following error: "Sorry! The application Battery (process com.incorporateapps.battery) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." Steps to reproduce: 1. Download the application from the Amazon App store. 2. Launch the application. 3. Verify the application crashes with the error message above. alogcat output indicated that your app was missing its application identifier. We were unable to figure out why this would be missing.

Surprisingly, that is not my app. They did not provide a stack trace. When I contacted them for clarification I was told someone would contact me with the real reason, but have not heard anything back.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed you have `android:orientation="portrait"` in your question.  Make sure in your manifest in the activity declaration actually has `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`.

android:orientation and android:screenOrientation are easily confused.  One locks the screen orientation and the other is just used by an UI widget for design purposes.

Comment: Yeah it is screenOrientation I was just typing from memory :-)

Comment: So if that is set correctly an onConfigChange does not appear in your manifest, then your app would not respond to keyboard or orientation changes. Is that all the information you received from Amazon?

Comment: Yeah they said "On slider interruption, app redirects to another activity".  So your saying if I have android:screenOrientation="portrait" , my app won't restart on keyboard opening? And I won't need onConfigChanged

Comment: I am saying if you DO NOT have android:configChange and DO HAVE android:screenOrientation="portrait" in your manifest then your app will ignore all configuration changes including keyboard slide.

Comment: Yeah that's what I assumed, Amazon testing shows different. Time to test again!